# Unable To Find Object Within SSMS Highlighted With Data Migration Assistant

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

There's a breaking change being highlighted in the Data Migration Assistant tool `Syntax issue on the source server` about the syntax of an object however I am unable to find this object.

I've searched in sys.objects, the Object Explorer Details in SSMS & using RedGate SQL Search but can't find an object with this name.

I've added details below -

- Database Compatability: 100 (2008) to 150 (2019) (The breaking change shows from combability 100 onwards through DMA)
- Object: 'DatabaseName'_DB_MGMT_SPEC

The errors from DMA -

> While parsing the schema on the source database, one or more syntax issues were found. Syntax issues on the source database indicate that some objects contain unsupported syntax due to which all assessment rules were not run on the object.

> Object ['DBName'_DB_MGMT_SPEC] has syntax errors. Incorrect syntax near ].. Error number 46010. For more details, please see: Line 2, Column 23.

I found this similar issue but no solution
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f9d9330-2e91-454e-b97d-7d4272e1e109/need-to-identify-object-mentioned-in-data-migration-assistant-for-sql-server-upgrade-from-2008r2-to?forum=sqlservermigration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, there are Database Audit Specifications that appear not to have been set up properly with the 'DatabaseName'_DB_MGMT_SPEC name, removing these removed the warnings from DMA